# Blazor Server (EF Core) and database connection

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Sorry for the rudimentary question.

I'm currently studying application development with Blazor Server and am having trouble connecting to a database.

I'm trying to use DI to connect to the database.
I created a code that uses the factory pattern as shown below, but an error occurs in the part that gets the connection string.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //error:CS0121  Inappropriate call between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContextFactory<TContext>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder>, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLifetime)' と 'BlazorSv.Models.FactoryExtensions.AddDbContextFactory<TContext>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder>, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLifetime)'

        services.AddDbContextFactory<BlazorSv.Models.SQLbeginnerContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
    }
```

I thought that the definition of the <Models.SQLbeginnerContext> part was ambiguous, so I wrote the hierarchy, but it didn't work.

What should I do about this error?
I want some advice

Below is SQLbegginerContext.cs that describes StartUp.cs and the factory pattern.

StartUp.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //error:CS0121  Inappropriate call between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContextFactory<TContext>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder>, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLifetime)' と 'BlazorSv.Models.FactoryExtensions.AddDbContextFactory<TContext>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder>, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLifetime)'

        services.AddDbContextFactory<Models.SQLbeginnerContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

SQLbegginerContext.cs

```
public interface IDbContextFactory<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    TContext CreateDbContext();
}

public class blazordbFactory<TContext> : IDbContextFactory<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    public blazordbFactory(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;
    public TContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TContext>(provider);
    }
}

public static class FactoryExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddDbContextFactory<TContext>(
        this IServiceCollection collection,
        Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction = null,
        ServiceLifetime contextAndOptionsLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        collection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(
            typeof(IDbContextFactory<TContext>),
            sp => new blazordbFactory<TContext>(sp),
            contextAndOptionsLifetime));
        collection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(
            typeof(DbContextOptions<TContext>),
            sp => GetOptions<TContext>(optionsAction, sp),
            contextAndOptionsLifetime));

        return collection;
    }
    private static DbContextOptions<TContext> GetOptions<TContext>(
        Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> action,
        IServiceProvider sp = null) where TContext : DbContext
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>();
        if (sp != null)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseApplicationServiceProvider(sp);
        }
        action?.Invoke(optionsBuilder);
        return optionsBuilder.Options;
    }
}


public partial class SQLbeginnerContext : DbContext
{
    public SQLbeginnerContext()
    {
    }

    public SQLbeginnerContext(DbContextOptions<SQLbeginnerContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```

追記：SQLbegginer.cs

```
//Comment out this part
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder){
 if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
      optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost; Database=SQLbeginner; Username=user; Password=****")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are these custom `IDbContextFactory<TContext>`, `blazordbFactory<TContext>` and `FactoryExtensions`? Because EF Core provides such out-of-the-box, and these are clashing with EF Core ones.

Comment: thank you.
This code is a copy of the sample code on github.

Does this mean that EF Core isn't appropriate?

I'm sorry, my English is not good.
Also, I'm sorry I didn't answer the question properly.

Comment: I mean, EF Core has all these methods. I don't know what github sample code are you following and whey these 3 custom things were added there, so I would comment them out and leave just the `SQLbeginnerContext` class.

Comment: sorry.
I didn't know if I could post it because it was someone else's code.

I added the code to the question column.
There is an OnConfiguring method in SQLbegginer.cs, and I commented out this part and wrote the code including IDbContextFactory <TContext>, blazordbFactory <TContext> and FactoryExtensions.
Do you mean this part of the clashing?

Comment: You may have figured out why it didn't work.

The method I was writing was up to .Net Core3, and my environment was .Net5.

As advised, services.AddDbContextFactory <Models.SQLbeginnerContext> (options => options.UseNpgsql (Configuration.GetConnectionString ("DbConnection"))); works effectively by leaving only SQLbeginnerContext.
Now you don't have to embed the connection string in your code.

It was a very rudimentary mistake.
It took me more than 7 hours to deal with this problem and I was about to give up.
thanks so much.